# how to do multiple where with same field?

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

How to convert this script for mongoDB?

```
select * from table where id > -1 and id in (4,5)
```

I need to execute this query with two `where` conditions on the same field.

This doesn't seem to work in PHP:

```
$db->$col->find(
  array(
    'id' => array( '$gt' => -1 ),
    'id' => array( '$in' => array( 4, 5 ) )
  )
);
```

Comment: [so] is not an alternative to reading the documentation. Did you take a look at the docs? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: no documentation for the same field in where i got in there yet .. they just provide example with only one where.

Comment: `'id'=>array('$gt'=>-1, '$in'=>array(4,5))` tada

Comment: please @Sammaye update your as answer so i can make it as answer

Comment: @Lix : why you just downvote since i don't complete my question yet and the question is posted under 1 minute .. but ah no problem since this forum still help me a lot.

Comment: @kre - I downvoted because I don't feel that you put enough research effort into this issue before posting it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the problem is that you have a duplicate key in your array so the latter overwrites the prior so your query is only doing the `$in`.

Most poeople look to `$and` to solve this problem however, very few know that actually:

```
'id'=>array('$gt'=>-1, '$in'=>array(4,5))
```

Will also solve it. You can just chain your constraints for that field.